# Не удаётся выполнить ни Add-Migration, ни Update-Database

Tags: entity-framework, миграция

Добрый вечер. Суть проблемы в следующем: перестали применяться миграции в EF Code First.

После внесения изменений пытаюсь выполнить `Add-Migration <name>`, получаю сообщение:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are
>   pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the
>   pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic
>   migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to
>   true to enable automatic migration.

Попытка выполнить `Update-Database` приводит к той же ошибке.

По советам в интернете пыталась удалять папку с миграциями и таблицу _MigrationHistory, делать Build Batch - ничего из этого не помогло.

Пробовала полностью удалить БД и выполнить `Update-Database`, с нуля БД создается, но последующие изменения применить уже невозможно - та же ошибка в консоли.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли решение. Может, нужна какая-то дополнительная информация - я предоставлю. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Миграции ручками правили или нет? Не знаю, храните ли вы проект в версионном контроле и насколько хотите разобраться, где произошла поломка -- но всегда есть вариант начать жизнь с "чистого листа": удалите папку Migrations, удалите базу, заново начните с Enable-Migrations + Add-Migration MyInitMigration и в обычный цикл Update-Database - AddMigration - Update-Database - ...

Comment: вот здесь есть https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.12.php , а здесь именно ваш случай Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration  https://habrahabr.ru/post/143292/

Comment: @Eikhner Если вы работаете в команде, то избегайте автоматических миграций ([раз](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277915/) и [два](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735.aspx)). А ваш комментарий ни о чём: при включении миграций в проектах автоматом ставится AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false и представьте себе -- все работают и не жалуются! Тут именно что-то сломалось.

Comment: @AK, удалила папку и базу, получаю следующее:
PM> Enable-migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

Comment: @AK , друга ,  Мы не знаем , в команде работает ТС , или она пишет своё что то, может учебное  , тем более  - она уже удалила базу данных , суть не в этом . Суть в том , что подход Code First позволяет создавать контекст базы данных при каждом запуске приложения , равно как при этом и добавлять необходимые данные в созданную базу . Этим можно пользоваться при первом запуске приложения , потом закомментировать , и раскоментировать , когда добавили какое то новое поле в базу данных . И работать вообще без всяких миграций .

Comment: Нет ли в папке проекта файлов вида tmpE46D.tmp или подобных?

Comment: @AK, нет, не видно таких. Проект я делаю для себя (дипломная работа), так что снос БД пока не критичен. В папке была всего одна миграция. Я перепробовала уже все, что предлагалось, но не помогает. Пока что временно проблему решила удалением БД и миграций, сменила строку подключения, и новая БД создалась на основе модели. Но даже после этого включить или применить новые миграции после изменений не удаётся - та же ошибка.

Comment: @AK написала на почту. Спасибо Вам за отзывчивость. :)

Comment: Вы используете DbInitializer и его магию, что ведёт к разным путаницам (в EF7 DbInitializer вообще выпилили, так что и вы отвыкайте). Кинул в почту что конкретно нужно сделать в проекте.

Comment: @AK спасибо Вам огромнейшее. Вы сэкономили мне не один вечер, полный нервов и самобичевания.

Comment: Граф Толстой в романе Анна Каренина пишет, что все счастливые семьи похожи друг на друга (так же и хороший код похож у разных людей), а вот глюки бывают совершенно разные. В общем, я теперь знаю ещё один способ поломать миграции ;)

Comment: @AK Перед тем как сделать Enable-Migrations - нужно что-то удалить? Сделать clear/disable? У меня заглючило EF-вообще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/736024/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-ef-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83

Answer (score 5):

Я только один случай знаю из практики, когда можно получить описанную вами ситуацию.

Проверил на первом попавшемся проекте, где рабочая база и рабочие миграции.

Вот как я ломал:

1. создал в первой попавшейся таблице поле `Title1`
2. тут же сделал `Add-Migration Asdf1`
3. тут я должен был сделать `Update-Database` -- но я сделал вид, что я забыл применить миграцию через `Update-Database`, поэтому в этом шаге ничего не делаем
4. сделал в этой же таблице ещё одно поле `Title2`
5. выполняю  `Add-Migration Asdf2`

Вуаля: получаю ровно описанную вами ситуацию:

> PM> Add-Migration Asdf2
>
> Unable to generate an explicit migration
>   because the following explicit migrations are pending:
>   [201705272231565_Asdf1]. **Apply the pending explicit migrations before
>   attempting to generate a new explicit migration**.
>
> PM> Update-Database
>
> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied
>   to the target database. Applying explicit migrations:
>   [201705272231565_Asdf1]. Applying explicit migration:
>   201705272231565_Asdf1. Unable to update database to match the current
>   model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is
>   disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based
>   migration or enable automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration. You can use the Add-Migration command to write
>   the pending model changes to a code-based migration.
>
> PM>

(Выделил полужирным ключевой момент, вольный перевод: не забудьте применить миграцию перед тем как пытаться создавать новую)

Как чиню:

1. комментирую поле `Title2`
2. жму `Update-Database` (применяется миграция Asdf1)
3. раскомментирую поле `Title2`
4. выполняю `Add-Migration Asdf2`
5. выполняю `Update-Database`

Всё работает!

Проверьте, у вас возможно такая же ситуация. Меня смущает вот эта часть вопроса: "с нуля БД создается, но последующие изменения применить уже невозможно" -- выходит, вы несколько раз подряд забываете применить миграцию к базе перед созданием новой?

Comment: Проще говоря — необходимо удалить последний файл миграции и прописать по новой `add-migration -name 'name'`. Так?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk Ну если не жалко проделанной работы -- можно и последний файл миграции удалить. Но я не люблю давать советы со словом "удалить", особенно если я не уверен, что есть бекап и проект под версионным контролем. А представьте, что миграция не на одно поле?

Comment: Этот ответ правильный, описывает ОДНУ ИЗ возможных причины, поэтому если кто потом зайдёт из поиска -- проверьте и его тоже. Но в данном конкретном проекте оказалась совсем другая ситуация.

Answer (score 2):

Благодаря смекалке пользователя A K выяснилось, что выполнению команд мешал класс инициализатора БД и следующие строки:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationContext>(new DbInitializer());
Database.Initialize(true);
```

Причина в том, что Entity Framework 6 не позволяет использовать инициализаторы (например, DropCreateDatabaseAlways) вместе с миграциями.

Более подробно о проблеме:

1. If this initializer is used to create the database then a single entry is added to the __MigrationsHistory table which then renders the database un-usable with migrations (since these initializers don't use your migrations to create the database). This has confused a large number of people in previous releases, so we opted to not automatically create database/schema when migrations is enabled. Источник: [тык сюда](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1689)
2. It looks like EF 6.0 introduces a new rule:
   "If the DbContext is using an Initializer AND Migrations are configured, throw an exception when building the model". Источник: [тык сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430502/dropcreatedatabaseifmodelchanges-ef6-results-in-system-invalidoperationexception)

Может, это поможет кому-нибудь, кто, как и я, попал в подобную ситуацию.

Comment: Это ответ правильный и на него можете поставить галку, но... вы ведь так и не разобрались в причинах и не сможете объяснить, ПОЧЕМУ это помогло. Попробуйте почитать и разобраться самостоятельно когда будет время -- а потом дописать свой ответ.

Comment: @AK, выцепила вот что:
"EF 6.0 introduces a new rule: If the DbContext is using an Initializer AND Migrations are configured, throw an exception when building the model. This is throwing because you have migrations enabled and you are using the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges initializer. Entityframework does not support using this initializer with migrations."

Сейчас постараюсь обновить ответ с учетом полученной информации.

Comment: Вот теперь можно ставить плюс.

Comment: Ответ сделала общим, поэтому буду рада любым дополнениям.

Comment: про Initialize в Code First писалось выше в комментариях к самому вопросу, просто не захотели вникать  ...

Comment: @Eikhner прошу прощения, сейчас перечитала и поняла, о чем речь. А тогда не поняла, что имелось в виду. :)