# Недопустимое имя столбца

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Переопределил `DbContext` и указал модель по которой буду работь с БД:

```
    public class EFDbContext: DbContext
    {   
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
```

Изменил свою модель Article, удалил одно поле в модели и удалил соответсвующей столбец из БД. В последующих обращениях к контексту все равно выполняется SQL запрос на несуществующее поле, отчего и ошибка:

> Недопустимое имя столбца

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Подход Code First? Миграцию делал?

Comment: Да, CodeFirst. Пробовал активировать миграции, но с подключенным Ninject не срабатывают.

Comment: Сделайте `DropCreateDataBaseIfModelChanged`

Comment: попробуите почитать - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671743  тут что то подобное обсуждалось . Если не поможет , или будет не понятно,  опишите ваш подход `Code First` - как он  реализован ...

Comment: NInject не должен влиять, EF никак на него не завязан.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте правильно использовать code first. Я без понятия, почему это не работает так, как вы сделали, но может быть стоит всё таки выполнить миграцию?