# Как в EF добавить таблицу?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Есть проект, понадобилось добавить в него таблицу. Всё бы хорошо, только таблица не появляется в базе после того как делаю drop database, ну и понятно получаю exception. (*добавил* да, таблица не появляется когда запускаю проект, я считал что удаление СУБД заставит её создать, для этого удаляю субд)  База МуSQL. Теперь по подробнее... В папку Entities\DataBase добавил таблицу

```
namespace MyProj.Domain.Entities.Database{
  public class Company{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public String Name { get; set; }
}}
```

Идём дальше. В документации написано смотреть Entities\Migrations\Configuration.cs, смотрю...

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyProj.Domain.Concrete.MysqlEfDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        CodeGenerator = new MyCodeGenerator();
    }
```

Зашёл в `MysqlEfDbContext`

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MysqlEfDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; } // Дописал сюда таблицу, 
   // тут аналогично находятся другие таблицы
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Да, класс `MyCodeGenerator` - не содержит ссылок на таблицы. Не стал его публиковать.Там перехват метода `Generate` и вызов `StripDbo`, особенного не увидел.

До изменений - создавалась база, таблицы и всё работало. После изменений, создалась база без новой таблицы, и исключение

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there
>   are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write
>   the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable
>   automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration.

Ладно, раз пишут `true` - пусть, ставим  `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;`. Тогда получаю другую ошибку

> Table 'concreteperiods' already exists.

(это имя самой первой таблицы, которую нужно создать). Таблица *companies*, теперь создалась. Ошибка и первая и вторая появляется тут:

```
var user = (_repository.Users != null)?_repository.Users.
   ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username.Equals(model.UserName) 
 && x.Password.Equals(model.Password)) : null;
```

Смотрю что такое `_repository`

```
namespace MyProj.WebUI.Controllers
{
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private IProductRepository _repository;
    readonly IAuthProvider _authProvider;
    public AccountController(IAuthProvider auth, IProductRepository repo)
    {
        _repository = repo;
        _authProvider = auth;
    }
```

На `AccountController` ссылок нет.

Почитал про миграцию. Теперь история с миграцией.
Сделал в консоли Enable-Migrations. Студия нулячая - получил ошибку - не знаю команду. 
Сделал  правой мыши на проект -> восстановить пакеты.
Enable-Migrations

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
Code First Migrations enabled for project MyProj.Domain.
PM> Add-Migration "company"
The project 'MyProj.Domain' failed to build.
```

Смотрю на проект - у меня создалась в корень ещё одна папка Mirgations, и в ней ещё один файл Configuration.cs - и как результат - проект не собирается, т.к класс Configuration объявлен два раза. Удалил, повторил  Add-Migration "company" получаю ошибку веселее...

> PM> Add-Migration "company" System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на
>   объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.    в
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    в
>   MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection)    в
>   ...
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>   в System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   в System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean
>   ignoreChanges)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name,
>   Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)    в
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   в System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command)

EntityFramework версия 6.0.0.0, среда выполнения v 4.0.30319

VS 2017

Что ещё можно посмотреть, есть ли где ещё список таблиц, которые нужно создать при "первом запуске"?

Comment: Не указал, первый раз открыл проэкт с MVC + EF. Вроде всё понятно... но... До этого на чистом с# - всё на виду.

Comment: вам ничто не мешает создать таблицу руками.

Comment: @free_ze создал - получаю другое исключение `The model backing the 'MysqlEfDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database` Как ему обьяснить что структура не изменилась?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После добавления новой таблицы вы должны [создать миграцию](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level2/2_11.php).

Вводим в [консоль диспетчера пакетов](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc748979(v=ws.10).aspx) (Pkgmgr.exe):

- `Enable-Migrations` - включение миграций.
- `Add-Migration "Название"` - добавление новой миграции.
- `Update-Database` - обновление DB.

**UPDATED:** или вы можете [создать свой инициализатор](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.9.php), унаследовать его от `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<T>` и пересоздавать базу при каждом запуске (при этом теряются данные).

Comment: Не понятно, дайте ссылку на источник, или это в VS в меню искать?

Comment: Открываете консоль диспетчера пакетов и вводите туда. Вот, например: https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level2/2_11.php

Comment: Читаю ссылку, лучше её в ответ;). Сейчас копаюсь, теперь понятна концепция. А базу я делал drop, для того что бы создалась новая, полагая, что "новая" будет идеальной, а старую я сам "допилю", не зная что есть "миграция".

Comment: PM> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName "MyProj.Domain"
Имя "Enable-Migrations" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла скрипта или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания им
ени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.

Comment: Наверно чего-то не хватает, но где создаются таблицы я нашёл. Попробую в Migrations добавить файл вида *yyymmdd_reason.cs* думаю поможет.

Comment: @nick_n_a, попробуй переустановить пакет `Install-Package EntityFramework`, затем перезапусти студию и выполни еще раз

Comment: PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
Install-Package : В этом решении отсутствует несколько пакетов NuGet. Необходимо восстановить пакеты, чтобы построить график зависимостей. Восс
тановите пакеты, прежде чем выполнять какие-либо операции.

Comment: @nick_n_a, правой мыши на проект -> восстановить пакеты

Comment: В МуSQL помнится какие-то нюансы были с миграциями

Comment: Допишите что команды нужно вводить в консоли NuGet, тогда ответ будет выглядеть завершённым.